# Can't query a string from an SQL table

Tags: delphi, ado, tadoquery

I am trying to pass the value of a group from the database into a `TEdit` when an item is selected in a `TComboBox`. However, the value returned should be a string, not an integer. In the text field for the group, the value returned is 0. Can anyone help me with this?

This is the code for the text field that should return the group data based on the item selected in a `TComboBox`:

```pascal
ADOQuery1.SQL.Clear;
rf := ADOQuery1.SQL.Add('SELECT grouppp FROM f3_sheet WHERE holder =  "' +cb1.Text +'"');
gpp.Text := rf;
```

Answer (score 7):

The [`TADOQuery.SQL`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Data.Win.ADODB.TADOQuery.SQL) property is a [`TStrings`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.Classes.TStrings) object. Its [`Add()`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.Classes.TStrings.Add) method returns the *index* of the string you just added to the list.  That is why the return value is an integer `0` in your example.

But that is not what you want in this situation.  After you fill in the `SQL` statement as needed, you need to then actually *execute* that SQL on the database by calling the [`TADOQuery.Open()`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Data.DB.TDataSet.Open) method, and then you can read the retrieved field value from the [`TADOQuery.Fields`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Data.DB.TDataSet.Fields) collection, eg:

```pascal
ADOQuery1.SQL.Text := 'SELECT grouppp FROM f3_sheet WHERE holder = ' + AnsiQuotedStr(cb1.Text, '"');
ADOQuery1.Open;
try
  if not ADOQuery1.Eof then
    gpp.Text := ADOQuery1.Fields[0].AsString
  else
    gpp.Text := '';
finally
  ADOQuery1.Close;
end;
```

---

That being said, notice how I changed your SQL to use `AnsiQuotedStr()` instead of wrapping `cb1.Text` with quotation marks manually.  Your original code suffers from a potential *SQL Injection Attack*, if the user is allowed to enter arbitrary text into the `TComboBox`.

For example, if the user were to enter something like `"; DELETE FROM f3_sheet; --` into the `TComboBox`, your original code would end up executing this SQL:

```sql
SELECT grouppp FROM f3_sheet WHERE holder = ""; DELETE FROM f3_sheet; --"
```

And the contents of your database table would go **bye-bye**!

Making the `TComboBox` read-only is one way to mitigate that attack, so that only your code is allowed to specify valid strings that won't corrupt the SQL.

Using `AnsiQuotedStr()` is another way, by escaping embedded quotation marks in the user's text, eg:

```sql
SELECT grouppp FROM f3_sheet WHERE holder = """; DELETE FROM f3_sheet; --"
```

Now the SQL will search the `holder` field for the literal string `"; DELETE FROM f3_sheet; --` and not find any result.

However, the best way to avoid such an attack is to simply not create SQL statements by hand in the first place, use *Parameterized Queries* or *Stored Procedures* instead.  For example, the above example can be re-written to use Parameters like this:

```pascal
// make sure to set ADOQuery1.ParamCheeck=true beforehand...
ADOQuery1.SQL.Text := 'SELECT grouppp FROM f3_sheet WHERE holder = :PHolder';
ADOQuery1.Parameters.ParamByName('PHolder').Value := cb1.Text;
ADOQuery1.Open;
try
  if not ADOQuery1.Eof then
    gpp.Text := ADOQuery1.Fields[0].AsString
  else
    gpp.Text := '';
finally
  ADOQuery1.Close;
end;
```

Let the database handle any quoting and escaping requirements for you.

Comment: Would be nice also to explain the OP how to use a parametrized query instead of building a string for the SQL query.

Comment: @fpiette that is not really the focus of the question at hand, but OK, I've added it.